# Android Killing PhoneGap application

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm quite new to Android world and I have been developing an Android application with Phonegap (Jquery) that communicates with a Background Service (Java) that reports GPS location every 10 secs. The memory consumption is usually around 30MB, not that much, however I have perceived that Android, for some reason, kills my application after a while, probably because it needs more memory.

So, Is there a way of avoiding that? If not, how can I detect when the application is being killed?

Comment: Is it memory or ANR due to too much work on UI thread. Post your logcat when you app is killed.

Comment: It's not ANR. After opening a few applications, I touch to open my app and it's like restarted, No error happens. Any idea of how to avoid or fix that?

Comment: You can't avoid the OS killing your app due to memory pressure, as that is what it was designed to do. If you can't find a way to recover gracefully as a webapp, you might have to consider converting to a native Java app.

Comment: Hello Chang! Thx for the answer. If I migrate to a native app, will it not be susceptible to happen too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is getting killed by the OS due to normal usage memory pressure, there is no way to avoid that as that is what the OS was designed to do with backgrounded apps.

You will have to find a way to recover gracefully but your webapp is starting as if it was newly launched.

As an alternative you can convert your app to a native app. While the same thing is happening with a native app, its happening much quicker as all of the UI elements are native UI elements (buttons, text fields, etc.) while in a webapp you are injecting HTML and JavaScript into a WebView and depending on the Webkit engine to render everything. Should you go the native route, the documentation and tutorials available at [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) are available.

Comment: I'll consider in migrating into a native app rather than webapp. Thanks a million for the answer Chang!